# How to separate data by minute into a csv file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a CSV dataset and a column is timestamp type:

[image]

I wanna separate and select data every minute and then copy it to a new CSV file.

For example all 12:35 on a file and also 12:36 and 12:37

How should I check the time and select data?
What is the best solution for this issue?

```
import pandas as pa
df = pa.read_csv('testdataset.csv')
for row in df:
    df1 = df.loc[df['received_time'] == ??????]
df1.to_csv('final.csv')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`pandas.Grouper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) and a `freq='1min'` to group the data by minutes.
- The times need to be converted to a `datetime64[ns] dtype`, for `.Grouper` to work.

  - `format` doesn't need to be specified, because `.to_datetime` can infer the format, however, specifying an explicit format, makes the conversion faster, especially for large datasets.
- Iterate through the groupby object and save the group for each minute to a dataframe, without the `'datetime'` column that was created for `.Grouper`

```py
import pandas as pd

# extended test dataframe used for this example
data = {'message_type': [302, 302, 300, 300, 300, 302, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700],
        'received_time': ['12:35:41 AM', '12:35:41 AM', '12:35:41 AM', '12:35:41 AM', '12:35:41 AM', '12:35:41 AM', '12:36:55 AM', '12:36:55 AM', '12:36:55 AM', '12:36:42 AM', '12:37:42 AM', '12:37:42 AM', '12:37:43 AM', '01:37:43 AM', '11:37:43 PM', '03:36:43 AM', '11:37:43 AM']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# display(df)
    message_type received_time
0            302   12:35:41 AM
1            302   12:35:41 AM
2            300   12:35:41 AM
3            300   12:35:41 AM
4            300   12:35:41 AM
5            302   12:35:41 AM
6            300   12:36:55 AM
7            300   12:36:55 AM
8            300   12:36:55 AM
9            300   12:36:42 AM
10           300   12:37:42 AM
11           300   12:37:42 AM
12           300   12:37:43 AM
13           400   01:37:43 AM
14           500   11:37:43 PM
15           600   03:36:43 AM
16           700   11:37:43 AM
```

```py
# if not using the test dataframe, read the data from the file
# df = pa.read_csv('testdataset.csv')

# create datetime column
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df.received_time, format='%I:%M:%S %p')

# groupby with Grouper, and save to csv
for g, d in df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='datetime', freq='1min')):

    # grouper infers even missing minutes, so we only want files for minutes that exist
    if not d.empty:

        # : can't be used in a file name, so they must be removed
        filename = str(g.time()).replace(':', '')

        # use .iloc to select the data without the datetime column and save 
        d.iloc[:, :-1].to_csv(f'{filename}.csv', index=False)
```

#### Saved Files

`003500.csv`

```
message_type,received_time
302,12:35:41 AM
302,12:35:41 AM
300,12:35:41 AM
300,12:35:41 AM
300,12:35:41 AM
302,12:35:41 AM
```

`003600.csv`

```
message_type,received_time
300,12:36:42 AM
300,12:36:55 AM
300,12:36:55 AM
300,12:36:55 AM
```

`003700.csv`

```
message_type,received_time
300,12:37:42 AM
300,12:37:42 AM
300,12:37:43 AM
```

`013700.csv`

```
message_type,received_time
400,01:37:43 AM
```

`033600.csv`

```
message_type,received_time
600,03:36:43 AM
```

`113700.csv`

```
message_type,received_time
700,11:37:43 AM
```

`233700.csv`

```
message_type,received_time
500,11:37:43 PM
```

Comment: Thanks, my problem solved. I changed format like "format='%M:%S.%f"

Answer (score 0):

I use the following method:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('testdataset.csv')

df['minute'] = df['received_time'].str.slice(stop=5)

for g, d in df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='minute')):
    d.to_csv(
        g.replace(':', '_') + '.csv',
        columns=['message_type', 'received_time'],
        index=False
    )
```

As commented by @Trenton McKinney, the solution could not differentiate time in the AM and PM, such as "11:35:11 AM" and "11:35:11 PM".

The updated code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('testdataset.csv')

df['minute'] = df['received_time'].str.slice(stop=5) + \
               df['received_time'].str.slice(start=9)

for g, d in df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='minute')):
    d.to_csv(
        g.replace(':', '_') + '.csv',
        columns=['message_type', 'received_time'],
        index=False)
```

Comment: (1) the way this is implemented, `pd.Grouper` isn't need. `df.groupby('minute')` will do the same thing. (2) this doesn't differentiate between AM and PM so `'11:37:43 PM` and `'11:37:43 AM'` would get grouped together, because both are `'11:37'` in your `'minute'` column.

Comment: You can separate AM and PM into a new column and then groupby 2 columns.